# Is there a difference in Object.assign {} and Object.Assign []

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am going through some old code from a defunct developer and noticed that sometimes he used

```
Object.assign({}, xyz)
```

and others he used

```
 Object.assign([], abc);
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. One assigns the values to a new object and the other assigns the values to a new array.

Look at the output here and compare to the output in the actual browser console.

```js
var abc = {foo:"bar"};

var r1 = Object.assign({},abc);
var r2 = Object.assign([],abc);

console.log(r1);
console.log(r2);
```

What the second one *doesn't* do is add a new item to the array - it still has a length of 0.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.assign` is a function that copies the *enumerable* *own* properties from one object to another (called target) and returns the target object. Since arrays are also objects you can copy properties to them as well, however, they won't show up during iteration.

Take the following snippet for example:

- `obj` is an `object`
- `arr` is an `object`, but also an `array`
- `arr.a` is 1
- `arr.forEach` does not print `a`

```js
const obj = Object.assign({}, {
  a: 1,
  0: 2
});
const arr = Object.assign([], {
  a: 1,
  0: 2
});

console.log(typeof obj);
console.log(typeof arr);

console.log(Array.isArray(arr));

console.log(obj);

console.log(arr);
console.log(Object.keys(arr));
console.log(arr.a);

arr.forEach((item, idx) => console.log(`${idx}: ${item}`));

// To test the question in the comments

let copiedObj = { a: 123 };

let copy = Object.assign({}, copiedObj);

console.log(copy);

copiedObj = [];

console.log(copiedObj);
console.log(copy);
```

Comment: So what causes the copied object to change? Lets say that I assign obj as you have done. Then I change a:1 to a:435 and 0: bbb. Why is it that I find that my obj is also changed? Isn't is supposed to be a copy?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean if you do `obj.a = 435` you can expect it to change.

Comment: Yea for some reason if I copy the object for example: const obj = Object.assign({}, abc); Then on the next line I do abc = []; Then obj will also = []; For some reason the copied object is still linked to my original object even though it is supposed to be a copy of it.

Comment: @CodeMan03 I added your example to the snippet, I can't reproduce

Comment: I figured it out I needed to clone deep. I had an object within an object and the imbedded object was getting changed. I also couldn't use Json.parse(Json.stringify(object)) as the imbedded object needed to preserve javascript dates. So I installed lodash cloneDeep